# Kotlin connect to database

Tags: mysql, kotlin

Hello I am new to kotlin and coding. I try to connect my app with a database using Android studio and XAMPP. But when i launch the app it shows failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 but if i used the function PING it works. Can anyone helps ? I have been looking to differents pages but i did not find a proper answer.

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //RetrieveFeedTask().execute(urlToRssFeed)
        Test.connection()
    }
}
```

```
import android.os.StrictMode
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException

object Test {

    @JvmStatic
    fun connection(){
        try {
            println("\nOK  1 ! \n")
            val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
            val connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student?user=rootupdater&password=test1234")
  //          val connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student", "rootupdater", "test1234")
//            val connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student?serverTimezone=UTC", "rootupdater", "test1234")
            println("\n OK 2 ! \n")
            val state = connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)
            val reques = state.executeQuery("SELECT `id`, `Name`, `lastName`, `city` FROM `info` WHERE 1")

            reques.next()
            val str_Nom = reques.getString("Name")
            println(str_Nom)
        }
        catch (e : SQLException){
            println("\nNOT OK  2 ! \n")
            e.printStackTrace()
            println("\nNOT OK  1 ! \n")

        }
    }
}
```

```
 OK  1 ! 
2022-11-24 10:09:15.198 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess I/System.out: 
2022-11-24 10:09:15.198 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess I/System.out: NOT OK  2 ! 
2022-11-24 10:09:15.198 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess W/System.err: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2022-11-24 10:09:15.198 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess W/System.err: 
2022-11-24 10:09:15.198 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess W/System.err: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2022-11-24 10:09:15.201 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess W/System.err: 
2022-11-24 10:09:15.201 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess W/System.err: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 3306) from /:: (port 53120): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2022-11-24 10:09:15.202 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:142)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2022-11-24 10:09:15.203 3672-3672/com.example.mydbaccess W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
 NOT OK  1 ! 
2022-11-24 10:09:15.290 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf691f340, tid 3694
2022-11-24 10:09:15.294 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-11-24 10:09:15.297 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-11-24 10:09:15.332 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf691f2d0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2022-11-24 10:09:15.366 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf691f2d0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf6c757d0) (first time)
2022-11-24 10:09:15.374 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-11-24 10:09:15.401 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-11-24 10:09:15.401 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf691fce0, tid 3694
2022-11-24 10:09:15.402 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2022-11-24 10:09:15.404 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f3ffe000 size 0x2000
2022-11-24 10:09:15.412 3672-3694/com.example.mydbaccess D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-11-24 10:09:16.563 3672-3688/com.example.mydbaccess W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

First, I'd like to connect the database, then update the data on the app I am working with Android Studio and XAMPP.

Comment: Not suggested to directly connect an Android app with MySQL. You should use a wrapper to create an API in web server to handle the requests. Also, `localhost` in the Android app means the device itself. Does your MySQL server install in the Android device? I don't think so.

Comment: The error means that the connection request did not even reach mysql server. Either it is not running at all, or is running on a different port, or firewall / OS blocks the connection or you are connecting to the wrong host.

Comment: MYSQL server is not install in the android device I tried to follow a tutorial on youtube but it is not working as I expected. I'll look into creating an API. Thank you!